# Show alert to user when get any kind of error in Retrofit2?

Tags: android, alert, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2 in my app for networking calls and i want to display alert to the user when get any kind of error in my app during networking calls. I can show alert to the user during networking call in override method of Retrofit but i do not want to write method for every networking calls, Is there any way to write only once that alert method when show whenever any error comes.

Any kind of help would be helpful for me.

Comment: I have added a possible solution @Rajeev,please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an Interceptor like below

```
 public static class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor
    {
      Context context;

      public LoggingInterceptor(Context context)
         {
            this.context = context;
         }

      @Override
      public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException
         {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            response.code();
            if(response.code() != 200)
            {
              backgroundThreadShortToast(context, "response code is not 200");
            }
            else
            {
              backgroundThreadShortToast(context, "response code is 200");
            }
            return response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), "")).build();
            //return response;
         }
    }

 public static void backgroundThreadShortToast(final Context context, final String msg)
    {
      if(context != null && msg != null)
      {
         new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
            {

              @Override
              public void run()
                 {
                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            });
      }
    }
```

and then add this interceptor to your main retrofit client

```
    client.interceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor(context));
```

In the above case, a toast will be for the response code == 200.

Hope it helps.

Comment: well i tested the code before posting. Can you tell me what error are you getting?

Comment: @Morya Is there a way to implement this when using retrofit instance as a Singleton, because the context passed to the interceptor will always be of the first activity that was started

Comment: @John There are few possible solution's in case of singleton. 1) The dirty one, create an Alert dialog activity and launch it when you have an error with any context you have in singleton class. 2) Use EventBus to emit the event from singleton class and receive it in BaseActivity.java class 3) Using system permission alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT); click here [https://medium.com/@nhancv/android-show-dialog-without-activity-context-94661d48400]

Comment: @Morya Well I ended up throwing custom exception classes and handling it in the `onFailure` method. Again in the `onFailure` method I ended up using a static helper method to process the exception. I passed the context of the current activity to this helper method which is used to display Toast, startActivity or show AlertDialogs

Answer (score 0):

In its onFailure method you can show Toast to user by doing as below:

```
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(yourContext, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a utility class and create a method for alert Dialog for network error like this:

```
public static void showNetworkDialog(context){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Network Error");

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Check Internet Connection!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Then in your webservice calling failure method just call the above method:

```
@Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
               Utils.showNetworkDialog(context);

            }
        });
```